# How to connect RabbitMQ Queue into Socket IO server and send messages from Socket IO server to client concurrently

Tags: python, rabbitmq, python-asyncio, aiohttp, python-socketio

Im trying to get work Rabbit MQ queues through AioPika to send messages to Socket Io server and server would send those messages to client based on there SID, UID, etc. Documentation for using rabbitmq on socket is almost non existent. I am able to send messages to exchange with rabbit mq producer but socket io server don’t receive anything. But even if i would receive some message from rabbitmq i don’t  now how to send message to the client. Because if i put `sio.emit(...)` into `def main()` `sio.emit` is never reached because `web.run_app(app)` run constantly in loop.
Im using local rabbit mq. How to make the running app and sending messages so they can run independent. Thank you for every hint and help. Really appreciated.

Socket IO code:

```
from aiohttp import web
import socketio
import redis

mgr = socketio.AsyncAioPikaManager(channel="Socket io test")
sio = socketio.AsyncServer(client_manager=mgr)
app = web.Application()
sio.attach(app)


async def redis_sio_uid_write(sid):
    client = redis.Redis(db=0)
    client.set(sid, "uid")


async def redis_sio_uid_delete(sid):
    client = redis.Redis(db=0)
    client.srem(sid, "uid")


@sio.event
async def connect(sid, environ):
    """Connect and print "connection established" message."""
    await redis_sio_uid_write(sid)
    print('Connection Established', sid)


@sio.event
async def disconnect(sid):
    """Disconnect and print "disconnected from server" message."""
    print('disconnected from server', sid)


def main():
    web.run_app(app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
'''
```

Rabbit MQ Producer:

```
import sys
import asyncio
from aio_pika import connect, Message, DeliveryMode, ExchangeType


async def main(loop):
    # Perform connection
    connection = await connect(loop=loop)

    # Creating a channel
    channel = await connection.channel()

    socketio_exchange = await channel.declare_exchange(
        "Socket io test", ExchangeType.FANOUT
    )

    message_body = b"Hello World!"

    message = Message(
        message_body,
        delivery_mode=DeliveryMode.PERSISTENT
    )

    # Sending the message
    await socketio_exchange.publish(message, routing_key="")

    print(" [x] Sent %r" % message)

    await connection.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main(loop))
```

ok so i solve the concurrent part with threading but still dont know ho to connect the rabbit mq onto socket io server.

socketio server:

```
from aiohttp import web
import socketio
import redis
import time
import random
import asyncio
from threading import Thread, Event, Lock

mgr = socketio.AsyncAioPikaManager(channel="Socket io test")
sio = socketio.AsyncServer(client_manager=mgr)
app = web.Application()
sio.attach(app)
loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()


def side_thread(loop):
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    loop.run_forever()


thread = Thread(target=side_thread, args=(loop,), daemon=True)
thread.start()


async def redis_sio_uid_write(sid):
    client = redis.Redis(db=0)
    client.sadd(sid, "".join([str(random.randint(1, 10)) for _ in range(10)]))


async def redis_sio_uid_delete(sid):
    client = redis.Redis(db=0)
    client.spop(sid)


@sio.event
async def connect(sid, environ):
    """Connect and print "connection established" message."""
    await redis_sio_uid_write(sid)
    print('Connection Established', sid)


@sio.event
async def disconnect(sid):
    """Disconnect and print "disconnected from server" message."""
    await redis_sio_uid_delete(sid)
    print('disconnected from server', sid)


async def _data():
    while 1:
        await sio.emit(event="message_rabbit_mq", data=time.time())
        await asyncio.sleep(5)


def main():
    future = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(_data(), loop)
    future.add_done_callback(web.run_app(app))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for your use case is here: [Emitting from external processes](https://python-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/server.html#emitting-from-external-processes).

From the documentation, the example for a Redis queue is as follows:

```py
# connect to the redis queue as an external process
external_sio = socketio.RedisManager('redis://', write_only=True)

# emit an event
external_sio.emit('my event', data={'foo': 'bar'}, room='my room')
```

You would need to replace `RedisManager` with the aiopika manager, but other than that everything works the same. In case it isn't clear, you do not need to manage anything on the RabbitMQ side, you should use the client manager class both on the server and the external process scripts.